# Making Collision Detection more Efficient

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision-detection, tile

I'm working on an HTML5-canvas game, where the map is randomly generated 10px by 10px tiles which the player can then dig and build upon. The tiles are stored in an array of objects and a small map contains about 23000 tiles. My collision detection function checks the players position against all non-air tiles every run through (using `requestAnimationFrame()`), and it works perfectly but I feel like it's CPU intensive. Collision function is as follows (code came from an online tutorial):

```
function colCheck(shapeA, shapeB) {
    var vX = (shapeA.x + (shapeA.width / 2)) - (shapeB.x + (shapeB.width / 2)),
    vY = (shapeA.y + (shapeA.height / 2)) - (shapeB.y + (shapeB.height / 2)),
    hWidths = (shapeA.width / 2) + (shapeB.width / 2),
    hHeights = (shapeA.height / 2) + (shapeB.height / 2),
    colDir = null;

    // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they we must be inside the object, causing a collision
    if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {         
        // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)         
        var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),             
            oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);         
        if (oX >= oY) {
            if (vY > 0) {
                colDir = "t";
                shapeA.y += oY;
            } else {
                colDir = "b";
                shapeA.y -= oY;
            }
        } else {
            if (vX > 0) {
                colDir = "l";
                shapeA.x += oX;
            } else {
                colDir = "r";
                shapeA.x -= oX;
            }
        }
    }
    return colDir;
};
```

Then within my update function I run this function with the player and tiles as arguments:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    //the tiles tag attribute determines rendering colour and how the player can interact with it ie. dirt, rock, etc. 
    //anything except "none" is solid and therefore needs collision
    if (tiles[i].tag !== "none") {
        dir = colCheck(player, tiles[i]);
        if (dir === "l"){
            player.velX = 0;
            player.jumping = false;
        } else if  (dir === "r") {
            player.velX = 0;
            player.jumping = false;
        } else if (dir === "b") {
            player.grounded = true;
            player.jumping = false;
        } else if (dir === "t") {
            player.velY *= -0.3;
        }
    }
};
```

So what I'm wondering is if I only check tiles within a certain distance from the player using a condition like `Math.abs(tiles[i].x - player.x) < 100` and the same for `y`, should that make the code more efficient because it will be checking collision against fewer tiles or or is it less efficient to be checking extra parameters?

And if that's difficult to saying without testing, how do I go about finding how well my code is running?

Comment: Imagine you have an array with the tiles sorted by x. Your character has 50 width and is in position 170. That means you only want to check tiles between 170 and 220. And that can be obtained in O(2 log2 n) operations, which means that for 10000 tiles, you can get the indexes of the tiles which have an x position between 170 and 220 in 2* 14 operations = 28. So you only check the tiles that are possible to intersect. Same can be done about y

Comment: One thing you can do is actually similar to the popular game *Minecraft*. Which is basically have a group of tiles belong to entire *"chunk"*. Then you can get the distance for each chunk and from that determine if you need to do collision detection of the items inside. So items far away would not have an collision detection and close-by ones can. But it depends on how the tile-system is setup. Of course there is overhead in distance calculation, but (depending on how it is setup) will save collision detection performance.

Comment: @juvian by checking collision with only nearby tiles like you said the amount of time spent checking for collision dropped by 40-60% and boosted performance noticeably on larger maps.

Comment: @spencer despite the increased performance it was still slow with ~180000 tiles so I might try taking your suggestion and divide the map into thirds (surface, mid, and deep) for larger maps and just check tiles within the third the player is in, definitely something I'll look into!

Comment: @TuckerFlynn not sure how are you checking the nearby tiles, but if you are using the method of your answer, you are still iterating over the 180000 tiles and doing a lot of times the math.abs, which might be slow. With my method you would only iterate over the tiles of your possible area, which depends on your tiles size and player size, but should be much less. Would need more details to make an example though

Comment: Be sure you also draw only the tiles that intersect the camera object. If tiles are properly stored you shouldn't need to iterate through them all to find those tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I feel like it's CPU intensive

CPU's are intended to do a lot of stuff very fast. There is math to determine the efficiency of your algorithm, and it appears that your current implementation is O(n). If you reduce the number of tiles to a constant number, you would achieve O(1), which is better, but may not be noticeable for your application. To achieve O(1), you would have to keep an index of the X closest tiles and incrementally update the index when closest tiles change. I.e. if the player moves to the right, you would modify the index so that the left most column of tiles are removed and you get a new column of tiles on the right. When checking for collisions, you would simply iterate through the fixed number of tiles in the index instead of the entire set of tiles.

> ...should that make the code more efficient because it will be checking collision against fewer tiles or or is it less efficient to be checking extra parameters?

The best way to answer that is with a profiler, but I expect it would improve performance especially on larger maps. This would be an O(n) solution because you still iterate over the entire tile set, and you can imagine as your tile set approaches infinity, performance would start to degrade again. Your proposed solution may be a good compromise between the O(1) solution I suggested above.

The thing you don't want to do is prematurely optimize code. It's best to optimize when you're actually experiencing performance problems, and you should do so systematically so that you get the most bang for your buck. In other words even if you *did* have performance problems, the collision detection may not be the source.

> how do I go about finding how well my code is running?

The best way to go about optimizing code is to [attach a profiler](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling) and measure which parts of your code are the most CPU intensive. When you figure out what part of your code is too slow, either figure out a solution yourself, or head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask a very specific about how to improve the section of code that isn't performing well and include your profiler information and the associated section of code.

Comment: Great explanation of how efficiency is determined, and also the profiler is a great resource I had no idea about. I'm posting my results from using it as an answer in case anyone else is interested!

Answer (score 0):

In response to Samuel's answer suggesting I use a profiler:

With a map made up of ~23 000 tiles in an array:
The original collision code was running 48% time. By changing `if (tiles[i].tag !== "none")` to the following the amount of time spent checking for collisions dropped to 5%.

```
if (tiles[i].tag !== "none" 
    && Math.abs(tiles[i].x - player.x) < 200 
    && Math.abs(tiles[i].y - player.y) < 200)
```

With a map made up of ~180 000 tiles:
The original collision code was running 60-65% of the time and performance of the game is so low it can't be played. With the updated code the collision function is only running 0.5% of the time but performance is still low, so I would assume that even though less tiles are being checked for collision there are so many tiles that checking their position relative to the player is causing the game to run slowly.

Comment: I would say if you reduced collision detection to .5% then your slowness is probably coming from something else now